# jquery validate plugin 1.14 submitHandler submit syntax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a simple contact form in html using the jq 1.14 validator and jq 1.11.3. The form is submitting via ajax to my php script. Its all working but I have noticed some odd behavior and am hoping to get an answer here.  Here is the issue:
the form submits, receives the json and executes the .done function. Okay so then, I happened to hit the refresh when I changed some completely unrelated css on another part of the page and WHAM!, completely blank page with only the  from the  (my company name) what's more, the .ico on the window tab is the WRONG icon. It is a completely different .ico from a completely different project folder on my root (I use XAMPP). Now then, if I refresh again, everything goes completely back to normal.  I think it might have something to do with my submitHandler submitting twice or maybe a cache issue but I don't have a clue and couldn't find this behavior anywhere online.  I am am suspicious that I need to add a return false or a event.preventDefault but no matter where I have placed these in the submitHandler, the odd behavior remains.  I still have a lot to learn but I am just as suspicious that this might be a bug in the plugin itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#contactForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin

            debug: true,

            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 30
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 30
                },
                msg: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 256
                },
                human: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 1
                }
            }, // rules

            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Gotta have your name",
                    minlength: "Please include your complete name",
                    maxlength: "Name is too long. Please abbreviate."
                },
                email: {
                    required: "We really need your email address.",
                    minlength: "Email address is too short",
                    maxlength: "Email address is too long. Please contact us directly."
                },
                msg: {
                    required: "Please tell us what's on your mind.",
                    minlegth: "Your message is too short",
                    maxlength: "Your message is too long"
                },
                human: {
                    required: "You must provide an answer"
                }
            },  // messages

            submitHandler: function (form) {

                fdata = $(form).serialize();
                console.log("fdata is:  " + fdata);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "processContact.php",
                    data: fdata,
                    dataType: 'json'
                    })
                    .done(function(returnData, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        //console.log("returnData[0]:  " + returnData[0]);
                        //console.log("returnData[1]:  " + returnData[1]);
                        //alert("submitted!");
                        if (returnData[0] == "sent" && returnData[1] == "OK"){
                            //console.log("HIP HIP HOORAY!!");
                            $('#successCon').fadeIn("slow");
                        }
                        if (returnData[0] != "failed" && returnData[1] != "NOTOK"){
                            $("errorCon").html("<p><i><strong>" + returnData[0] + "</strong></i></p>")
                        } else {
                            $("#errorCon").html("<p>There was a problem sending your message.  Please contact us directly via <i><strong>contact [at] tunetakeout (dot) com</strong></i></p>").fadeIn("slow");
                        }
                        })
                        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("failed!" + textStatus, errorThrown);
                        })
                        .always(function() {
                            $("#contactForm :input").prop("disabled", true);
                        });

                return false;

            }  // submitHandler

    });  // validate

}); // document.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name"><span class="required"></span></label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name..." maxlength="30" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="required"></span>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email..." maxlength="30" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for ="name"><span class="required"></span></label>
                                <textarea  class="form-control" name="msg" style="height: 120px;" placeholder="Write your message (256 character max)..."></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="human"><span class="required"></span></label>
                                <p>Are you human?</p>
                                <input type="number" name="human" class="form-control" placeholder="What is three times five divided by three?" maxlength="1" />
                            </div>
                            <button type ="reset" id="clear" name="clear" class="btn btn-grey">Clear</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-orange pull-right">SEND</button>
                        </form>
                        <div id="successCon" class="text-center"><p><i><strong>Thank you, your message was sent! We'll be in touch shortly.</strong></i></p></div>
                        <div id="errorCon" class="text-center"></div>
```

So, where should the return false or the event.preventDefault be placed? Do I need to rework the code to manually submit and if so, what would that look like?

Comment: You put the `return false` at the end of the custom `submitHandler` as you've done.  You do not need a `preventDefault()` at all, since the plugin is already taking care of all that.

Comment: You have `debug: true`, which is only used for debugging and will interfere with the normal submission of the form.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, I got rid of the debug:true and voila! it is is submitting properly and sending the right response.  Moreover, the odd refresh behavior is no longer happening.  You saved some degree of my sanity!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, where should the `return false` or the `event.preventDefault` be placed?

Put the `return false` at the end of the custom `submitHandler` as you've done. You do not need a `.preventDefault()` at all, since the plugin is already taking care of that.

---

Remove [the `debug: true` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug).

It's only used during debugging and will block the normal submission of the form.

> Prevents the form from submitting and tries to help setting up the validation with warnings about missing methods and other debug messages.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept. This answer solved my problem entirely.  Thanks again.